# Xcode Error Retrieving Developer Info?

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, provisioning-profile, apple-id

I am following this [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW6) and trying to add provisioning profiles and signing identities for a new apple-id. The problem is that when I add a new apple-id in Xcode -> Settings -> Accounts I am getting "Error Fetching Developer Info".
[image: Error Fetching Developer Info]

[This](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2013/Sep/msg00168.html) is about all I have found searching around on google. I've restarted Xcode multiple times to no avail. Has anyone encountered this error?

**How do I fix this issue?**

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

XCode > Preferences > Accounts

Retype password, then click the General tab.

Then, go back to the Accounts tab. The error disappeared.

I'm guessing there are a number of situations that can cause this issue, just wanted to post what worked for me.

Comment: @nischalhada – as people are reporting on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=developer%20portal&src=tyah) I believe Apple's Developer Portal is down for the upcoming WWDC keynote. https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/

Comment: its ok then ... i was afraid that i have got some bug in mine

Comment: do u know this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703234/how-can-i-solve-coredata-mogenerator-not-found-issue

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Xcode6 GM and found the error in the system.log. When communicating with the developer portal, my name contained special characters like è, ä, ü, ß etc. After the change to ae, ue and ss I could use my AppleID and all certificates were for the use of Xcode6 downloaded.

Check your "system.log" file with your konsole.app and check if you have an DVTDeveloperAccountErrorPortalResponseText in your communication as the following:

```
DVTDeveloperAccountErrorPortalResponseText=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>firstName</key>
    <string>René</string>
    <key>lastName</key>
    <string>Bärnshofer</string>
```

If yes, change your developer account name in the developer portal. That solved my problem.
But I guess there is an issue in the communication of the developer portal. In Xcode5.x all my accounts are working fine and my userLocale is correct. In Xcode6 my locale is US-EN and so I guess the special characters does not match or could not processed. I opened a bug report for that. Maybe Apple will fix the issue

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Super easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

"Error Fetching Developer Info" is also Xcode's way of telling you that the password is incorrect. Luckily it told me so in the console.

Answer (score 0):

"Error Fetching Developer Info" is also Xcode's way of telling you that the password has **expired**. Make sure you can log into the developer portal - if you haven't changed your password in the past year (?) you will get a message when logging on to the portal telling you to se up a new password. Do this on the portal then put the new password into XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Besides an incorrect/expired password, it might also be that you have Two-Step Verification (2FA) enabled - as was my case.

Disable it, then enter your password, and click on the "General" tab, and then click back on the "Accounts" tab in Xcode's Preferences.

Answer (score -1):

I had to verify my account at https://appleid.apple.com/.