# Xcode | Error Fetching Developer Info

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

Yesterday I created a Apple Developer account to publish my app. I know yesterday (08.06.15) Apple had its WWDC. At that time I couldn't create my account. But an hour after the WWDC I could create my account and the site was online. But the problem now is that xCode can't fetch my Developer informations. I think the problem is that I'm in 3 Apple Developer Teams. All of them have my name but only one of them is a signed Developer. But I don't know why I am in these teams. Is there a possibility to remove them or does anybody had the same problem in xCode?

**SystemLog**:

```
Xcode[1741]:  DeveloperPortal: Completed request 56EA1BB3-2D8A-4A06-8B71-E0EA74A9CB59 (failure): {
    requestUrl = "https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/listTeams.action";
    userString = "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.  If the problem persists, please contact Apple Developer Program Support.\nhttps://developer.apple.com/support";
```

I googled already and [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818508/xcode-error-retrieving-developer-info) didn't helped me.

Comment: Do what the error message suggests, it's the best solution available for you.

Comment: When you sign into the Member Center in a web browser, do you see these extra multiple teams? If not, I would suggest that you should delete all the info from the account pref pane in Xcode and start over.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add your account into xCode.

1. goto xcode -> preference -> account
2. add your account
3. select button "view Details"
4. click on refresh button in bottom-left to add your certificates.

and than try to submit your app into iTunes.

Comment: In such a problem the button "view Details" is disabled

Comment: first add your apple account in xcode. goto xcode -> preference -> account. here bottom-right there "+" button click on that and add apple ID.

Comment: Yes, it automatically starts fetching developer informations. The select button "view Details" can't be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me possibly because of typing wrong password.
Finally got it to work by:

Clicking "**+**" sign below the Apple IDs list > "**Add Apple ID...**"

Then just entered the exact Apple ID (case sensitive!) and Log In with the correct password.

After that it said "*The account already exists*", but fetched the account info successfully, showed Teams table and enabled "View Details..." button.